# Redux-form returns Proxy in OnSubmit handler

Tags: redux, redux-form

I try run the example code.

```
<form onSubmit={values => console.log("========>", values)}>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="firstName">First Nameeee</label>
      <Field name="firstName" component="Input" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
      <Field name="lastName" component="Input" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <Field name="email" component="Input" type="email"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

But when i handle the onSubmit event the param values returns an Proxy instead an object with input values.

```
//Console.log output
Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, _dispatchInstances: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: Event, type: "submit"…}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `this.props.handleSubmit(values => console.log("========>", values))`

instead of `values => console.log("========>", values)`

Answer (score 5):

You are supposed to wrap it into `handleSubmit` function (it is provided by redux-form), like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(values => console.log("========>", values))}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Nameeee</label>
            <Field name="firstName" component="Input" type="text"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <Field name="lastName" component="Input" type="text"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <Field name="email" component="Input" type="email"/>
          </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using redux, make sure that you're mapping `onSubmit` to your form component instead of mapping to `handleSubmit`.

What's the difference you might ask?

`handleSubmit` is a built in prop in the redux-form, it's injected with you wrap your vanilla react form with the redux-form `reduxForm()`. Read more about it here: https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/props.md/

`onSubmit` is the prop it *will* call after it's done doing validations, yada yada. Basically make sure you're passing your custom business logic to the component via `onSubmit` and not via `handleSubmit` or you'll get this mysterious Proxy object and get confused for awhile.